# Need help/Ideas for fighting adult red dragon

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

So I am in a campaign with 4 other players, and we are all pretty experienced with D&D. Recently we found out that we will be fighting an adult red dragon soon (possibly in its lair). The problem with this is that all of us are level 9. Our party consists of: a sorcerer (specialized in fire damage), a warlock/sorcerer, a druid, a blood hunter, and a barbarian. I cannot think of a way that we can logically win this fight, as the dragon should just fly around above using its fire breath until we either die or run. Our ranged damage output is very minimal as the sorcerer is focused mainly on fire damage which wont do anything to the dragon. Is there something that I am overlooking or simply not thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. To answer this question effectively, the site *really* needs the details about each of the PCs involved and—if you can—about the dragon and especially its lair (e.g. if the dragon's lair is the traditional cramped cave, it ain't doin' much flyin', and problem solved!). If the question can be edited to provide more information about the PCs—races, feats (if any), magic items, and so on—, I think the site could make adequate suggestions for tactics, but as it stands this is likely too broad. Thank you for participating and have fun!